# Equivalent Java Config for spring messaging xml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration-amqp

I am trying to implements spring batch remote chunking using rabbitMQ. I following this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages)

what are the equivalent java config for this

```
<int:channel id="requests"/>
<int:channel id="replies"/>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
    destination-name="requests"
    channel="requests"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="outgoingReplies"
    destination-name="replies"
    channel="replies">
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for INBOUND:

```
@Bean(AMQP_INPUT_CHANNEL)
public MessageChannel amqpInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inbound(SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer,  
                                         @Qualifier(AMQP_INPUT_CHANNEL) MessageChannel channel,
                                         Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter) {
    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer);   
    adapter.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);      
    adapter.setOutputChannel(channel);
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);   
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(5);        
    container.setQueueNames("Queue_Name");          
    return container;
}
```

For OUTBOUND:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel amqpOutboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "amqpOutboundChannel")
public AmqpOutboundEndpoint amqpOutbound(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    AmqpOutboundEndpoint outbound = new AmqpOutboundEndpoint(amqpTemplate);
    outbound.setRoutingKey("ERROR-QUEUE");
    return outbound;
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "amqpOutboundChannel")
public interface BatchServiceMessagingGateway {
    void sendMessage(String data);
}
```